# Why this "You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges."

Tags: android, admob

I dont know how this error comes, when i try this lots of times, so I saw differnt post in stackoverflow but i doent get solution. So after this i post this problem. I have a 2.3.3 android app that I am developing that I would like to add Admob ads onto.
My errors:

[image]

**Here is the my java files>**

```
package com.example.admobtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import com.google.ads.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Create the adView
         adView=(AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    }

}
```

**and main.xml files**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="**************"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**In graphical  layout**

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - com.google.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log) See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.

**Finally in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admobtest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here I also try this  `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"` instead  of `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"` but does not effects.

And I add **GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.1.0.jar**  from exterval jar files.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem you have to set your project build target to Android 3.2 or higher .

Check more details on this link .

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ (See Android Tab)

Answer (score 0):

i think you missing meta-data tag

```
    <meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

i hope that helps